How to customize the seek backward/forward interval of the "ARD Mediathek" media player?
The default seek backward/forward interval of the ARD Mediathek media player using the arrow keys ← and → (or alternatively J and L) is very large depending on the video length (e. g. for a video length of two hours, about 70 seconds). In my opinion, that is way too much. That's why I'm looking for a way to adjust the interval to my liking.
I tried to modify the aria-valuenow attribute value of the div.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower element.
const valueNow = document.querySelectorAll('.noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower')[0];

// seek backward 10 seconds
valueNow.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', valueNow.getAttribute('aria-valuenow') - 10);

// seek forward 10 seconds
valueNow.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', valueNow.getAttribute('aria-valuenow') + 10);

But this doesn't work, my value is immediately overwritten again. Besides, there is probably a more elegant way. The implementation should be done as a Tampermonkey userscript.
Update:
I found the relevant code sections in this JavaScript file.
Changing
this.handleSeek(b.getCurrentTime() - Math.max(10, Math.floor(.01 * b.getDuration())));

to
this.handleSeek(b.getCurrentTime() - 10);

and
this.handleSeek(b.getCurrentTime() + Math.max(10, Math.floor(.01 * b.getDuration())));

to
this.handleSeek(b.getCurrentTime() + 10);

leads to the desired result.
But of course it would be total overkill to insert the entire content of the file into Tampermonkey. So the question is how to implement the two small changes more efficiently.

The simplest way is to fetch the script, replace those lines and inject it into the page with GM_addElement:
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Script override
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  .
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.ardmediathek.de/live*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=ardmediathek.de
// @grant        GM_addElement
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==


fetch("3206.7523101b.js").then(res => res.text()).then( text => {
    text = text.replaceAll('Math.max(10,Math.floor(.01*b.getDuration()))', '10');
    GM_addElement('script', {
        textContent: text,
    });

});


EDIT:
Changes needed to make the script work on the /video page:

match the page https://www.ardmediathek.de/video/*.
fetch the correct relative url /ardplayer.1732812071121.js. (starts with backslash)
use a regex to replace the target lines.

Updated script:
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Script override
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  .
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.ardmediathek.de/live*
// @match        https://www.ardmediathek.de/video/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=ardmediathek.de
// @grant        GM_addElement
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==


fetch("/ardplayer.1732812071121.js").then(res => res.text()).then( text => {
    text = text.replace(/Math\.max\(10,Math\.floor\(\.01\*\S\.getDuration\(\)\)\)/g, '10');
    GM_addElement('script', {
        textContent: text,
    });

});


Isn't that very inefficient?

@ThreeYearOld how so? it's fetching a single file (786kB); the whole thing takes less than 60ms.

Because of the file size. Apart from that, I'm actually looking for an easy way to access and modify this.handleSeek and b.getCurrentTime() using the browser developer tools.

I voted up anway.

@ThreeYearOld you can use local overrides to achieve the same thing, it will save you a mere 786kb which in the context of this live video site is nothing.

Could you provide an example? I actually thought that with the right "paths" I could just access this.handleSeek and b.getCurrentTime(). For example, if a website script says let foo = bar, I can execute foo = baz from the browser console and assign a different value to the variable.

@ThreeYearOld here's a guide to setup local overrides. And no you can't just access any variable from the global scope.

Do I understand correctly that this means the entire file has to be overwritten locally? Why can't I just access global variables?

Any idea why the userscript is working here but not here? The current file is ardplayer.1732812071121.js.

@ThreeYearOld see the edit for an updated script and the explanation

Thank you very much! I forgot to mention that I'd already changed // @match        https://www.ardmediathek.de/live* to // @match        https://www.ardmediathek.de/*. But I didn't change the path, so it was just a missing slash. What's the advantage of a regular expression replacement compared to a simple replacement? By the way, the current file is already 2.71 MB in size.

@ThreeYearOld b.getDuration() is  now E.getDuration(), the regex will match any character at that position instead of hardcoding it.

Oh, I see. Thank you! However, I doubt that the letter will change every time, so I'll stick with the normal replacement for now. That // @run-at       document-start is unnecessary, by the way, isn't it?

@ThreeYearOld document-start is to make sure the override is inserted before the default page fetches the original script, if the original script is executed first, you can't overwrite it. Without it, Tampermonkey uses the default document-idle which might still work, but might cause inconsistencies.

I see. Thank you!

One more question: Why is the userscript working even without a leading slash within the file path here (URL with nested "folders") but not here (URL with only one "folder")?

@ThreeYearOld it does NOT work on either of those without the leading slash. If you look in the console logs, you'll see the fetch error.

That makes sense to me. Strange. It might have been the cache.

I managed to reproduce the behavior that caused confusion about the leading slash. Without the leading slash, if you visit this page first and then navigate to a video with at least one "folder" in its URL the userscript is still working. Buf after a page reload, it isn't working (as expected) anymore. So, as I suspected, it appears to be a cache issue.

@ThreeYearOld it's because the site is a single page application, userscripts are only loaded/matched when there is real navigation. You can just match the whole site to fix this @match   https://www.ardmediathek.de/*

Ah, I see. Thank you! I already did. But what do you mean by "fix this"?

@ThreeYearOld just a typo, I meant to type "fix it".

Well, that doesn't really make any difference to me. What I don't understand is what, you mean, would be fixed by @match https://www.ardmediathek.de/*.

@ThreeYearOld in my answer the script matches https://www.ardmediathek.de/live* and https://www.ardmediathek.de/video/*, I said "fix it" as in fix my ANSWER. I did not realize you had already changed it, that's it!

I still don't understand how the more general matching pattern fixes anything. The point was that the user script unexpectedly works without a leading slash on pages with at least one "folder" in the URL (if it was previously loaded by calling a page without a "folder" in the URL). The matching pattern doesn't change this. Anyway, you helped me a lot. Thank you very much again!

@ThreeYearOld As I have already explained; it's because its an SPA (single page application), once you have loaded ardmediathek.de all the navigations (within the same domain) are not "real" navigations, meaning they are not detected by Tampermonkey; scripts are not re-run, it is only on "real" navigation (navigation from different domain, bookmark, manually typing url, opening in new tab, reload, etc) that the script is executed (if it matches the real navigation's url).

eg: say your script only matches https://www.ardmediathek.de/live*, then you load https://www.ardmediathek.de/ in the address bar (real navigation), tampermonkey detects the navigation but since the url of the tab does match with the script's @match header, then it won't be loaded. After that if you navigate to /live or /video/ (SPA navigation), it is not detected. So in order to fix this you have to match the whole domain.

"but since the url of the tab does match with the script's @match header" You mean "does not match", don't you?

@ThreeYearOld sorry about that, just another typo. I hope everything is clear now.

All right. Thank you!
